# Issue with set cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I created a code for place a cookie in my Wordpresstheme. 
This function is connected with the init function from Wordpress.

I tried to run the function without the initfunction from Wordpress. But the result is the same. NO COOKIE

```
function cookietime() { 
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$wp_visit_time])) {
        // set a cookie for 1 hour
        setcookie('wp_visit_time', $current_time, time()+3600);
    }
 } 
add_action('init', 'cookietime');
```

Comment: where are you defining `$current_time`?

Comment: also.. `!isset($_COOKIE['wp_visit_time']`.. should be a string, not an undefined variable.

Comment: I found the issue now I am looking for the answer for solved this. This function works only in the functions.php file. I created an action "add_action('name', 'name php function')" normaly you can call the function with do_action('name'); but also this does not work :(